# Can we create a temporary table, getting a result in oracle through R and delete table afterwards?

Tags: r, oracle

I have a `.sql` file that basically creates a temporary table using multiple joins to form the data needed. Then I manually copy the result, paste it in Excel and delete the table afterwards in Oracle DB.

As the query is big, I don't think it would be a good idea to write an oracle query in R.

Is there any way by which I can directly run that `.sql` file through Rstudio and store the result in the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know R.

However, consider *moving* code you have into a **stored procedure**. You'd then - in a single line (hopefully) - call that procedure from R. It would do its job (populate the table) and you'd just use its contents in R.

Comment: A similar, optional approach would be to implement your table as a materialized view, then call a stored procedure from R to refresh the materialized view.

Comment: I second what @pmdba says about using an MV.  Creating tables on the fly is _very poor_ practice, to put it mildly.

Comment: I agree with both comments; though, I - somehow - understood (as title suggest that table is **deleted** (and not **dropped**) afterwards - that temporary table is created once and re-used many times, not created/dropped every time.